# Why isn't my Lottie animation showing in my React-native app?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, animation, lottie

I have a react-native view which has a Lottie animation in it, but the animation doesn't show at all, the screen is just yellow (background color of the enclosing view).

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View, 
} from 'react-native';
import LottieView from 'lottie-react-native';

export default class Splash extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
    
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null,
  };
    
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'yellow'}}>
        <LottieView
          style={{flex: 1}}
          source={require('../check.json')}
          autoPlay
          loop
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Does your lottie animation work? Have you tested it elsewhere like in https://lottie.cloud/app/index.html?

Comment: yes, I copied an animation from here https://lottiefiles.com/4149-check

Answer (score 7):

I added

`style={{flex:1}}`

to
`LottieView`

and it was fine.

Comment: Please explain how this solves the issue, further guidance can be found in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: I solved like 
   <LottieView style={{flex:1}} />

Answer (score 5):

I tried out the Lottie file that you provided and it does work.

Here is the code that I used in my `App.js` to get it working.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';
import LottieView from 'lottie-react-native';

export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <LottieView
          style={{flex: 1}}
          source={require('./check.json')} {/* I think your issue is that you have the wrong path for your lottie file*/}
          autoPlay
          loop
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Note in my project my `App.js` and my `check.json` are in the same folder.

[image: folder structure]

Here is a picture of it working

[image: lottie working]

Answer (score 3):

maybe it's width and height issue, you don't have these fields

```js
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';
import LottieView from 'lottie-react-native';

export default function Loading() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <LottieView
        source={require('../../assets/loading.json')}
        autoPlay
        loop
        style={styles.loading}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  loading: {
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: true, these fields solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Lottie works fine. Here on the top the animation is displayed and on the bottom view, name of the company can be displayed.

```js
import {StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import LottieView from 'lottie-react-native';
import {Text} from 'react-native-paper';

export default function SplashScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1 / 0.9}}>
      <LottieView
        style={{flex: 1}}
        source={require('../../assets/rocketLaunchAnime.json')}
        autoPlay
        loop
        resizeMode="cover"
      />
      <View style={{alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor: '#318ce7'}}>
        <Text style={{color: 'white'}} variant="headlineMedium">
          Powered by{' '}
        </Text>
        <Text style={{color: 'white'}} variant="displayLarge">
          XYZ
        </Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```